# angular js not rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was following the angular js tutorial ([this one to be precise](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02)). I tried adding the script in the head and body nothing it just shows: 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }} {{phone.name}} and {{phone.snippet}} as is...is there anything i could be missing?

```
<!doctype html>
   <html lang="en" ng-app="phonecatApp">
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>My HTML File</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="../resource/css/bootstrap.css">
   <script src="../resource/js/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="../resource/js/controllers.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl">
    <p>1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 }}</p>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="phone in phones">{{phone.name}}
            <p>{{phone.snippet}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Check your relative paths for the scripts or post your controllers.js content. Almost sure that the path is wrong.

Comment: Open chrome dev tools and reload the page.  Make sure all your scripts are loading in the network tab and that there aren't any errors in the console.  If that doesn't work put some 'console.log' statements at the bottom of your scripts to absolutely verify they are getting loaded and ran.

Comment: damn, i was being stupid...didnt check console, the scripts were not loading...i use eclipse, so i could click through to the scripts so i thought the path was fine...but it was not...fixed now, ..thanx lot guys...